# Excel VBA Function, multiple user defined ranges

Tags: vba, excel, function, range

I've been trying out the public function in excel to create my own formulas that me and my co-workers could use, however after a lot of googling I can't seam to solve this one.

What I'm trying to do in this example is to have a formula that the user can call upon by typing "=SumCells()" in a cell and then select the range to sum with a set of citeras that they also should select from the excel.

On top of this I would like the option where I could look at the Date criteria and if the Date is equal to a date from another cell + an integer from another cell that will add to x months to it, it will summarize that as well. [Data and criterias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzklB.png)

So once I use the formula it would look something like this. [Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgkp0.png)

```
Public Function SumCells(RangeToSum As Range, CriteraRange_1 As Range, Critera_1 As Range, CriteraRange_2 As Range, Critera_2 As Range, MonthsToAdd As Integer)

SumCells = Application.SumIfs(Range(RangeToSum), _
         Range(CriteraRange_1), Range(Critera_1).Value, _
         Range(CriteraRange_2), "=" & DateAdd("m", MonthsToAdd, Range(Critera_2).Value)) 
End Function
```

Appreciate any help and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Range 'wrappers' from the range objects.

```
Public Function SumCells(RangeToSum As Range, _
                         CriteraRange_1 As Range, Critera_1 As Range, _
                         CriteraRange_2 As Range, Critera_2 As Range, MonthsToAdd As Integer)

    SumCells = Application.SumIfs(RangeToSum, _
             CriteraRange_1, Critera_1.Value, _
             CriteraRange_2, DateAdd("m", MonthsToAdd, Critera_2.Value))

End Function
```

[image]